# AsyncTask in RecyclerView throws You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity on callback

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have got an RecyclerView Adapter which is being updated every few seconds. Every time it calls an AsyncTask which will retrieve the data from the server and then calls the following method which is inside the adapter:

```
public static void updateItem(final FavoritesViewHolder holder, DBHelper dbHelper, int position, Channel channel, Context context, boolean success) {
            Glide.with(context).load(channel.getAvatar())
                    .error(R.drawable.youtube_default_avatar)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.youtube_default_avatar)
                    .into(holder.channelAvatarView);
            dbHelper.updateFavorites(channels.get(position));
            Glide.get(context).clearMemory();
    }
```

(I removed a few lines, they don't have impact on this issue)

But if a user quickly closes the app or goes to another and the AsyncTask just called that method (yes, the AsyncTask is being cancelled, no worries about that, it finishes successfully and calls this method), Glide throws the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
                                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed(RequestManagerRetriever.java:134)
                                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:102)
                                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:87)
                                                                                    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:629)
                                                                                    at it.bjarn.xxx.xxx.adapters.FavoritesAdapter.updateItem(FavoritesAdapter.java:204)
                                                                                    at it.bjarn.xxx.xxx.tasks.FavoriteUpdateTask.onPostExecute(FavoriteUpdateTask.java:104)
                                                                                    at it.bjarn.xxx.xxx.tasks.FavoriteUpdateTask.onPostExecute(FavoriteUpdateTask.java:27)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

This is the onPostExecute() of my AsyncTask:

```
protected void onPostExecute(AsyncTaskResult<Channel> result) {
        if (result.getError() != null) {
            Log.e("FavoritesUpdateTask", "Exception while retrieving  results: " + result.getError().toString());
            Glide.get(mContext).clearMemory();
        } else if (isCancelled()) {
            Log.d("FavoritesUpdateTask", "Cancelled");
            Glide.get(mContext).clearMemory();
        } else {
            Log.d("FavoritesUpdateTask", "Succesfully returned channel object");
            FavoritesAdapter.updateItem(mHolder, mDbHelper, mPosition, result.getResult(), mContext, true);
        }
    }
```

//Edit:

I also tried to cancel the task from the adapter, since I can't cancel it from the Activity itself (FavoritesUpdateTask is inside the adapter, that's also where it gets called in the onBindViewHolder()):

```
@Override
public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    if (favoriteUpdateTask != null) {
        favoriteUpdateTask.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If AsyncTask is getting cancelled on moving out of activity, how is updateItem() method being executed ?

Comment: No look, the AsyncTask is finished, so it calls the updateItem() method on success. But if the user then closes the app or goes to another activity, it crashes. It's seriously something that happens in an instant. But if the method gets cancelled when it's not done yet, it still cancels the task and never calls updateItem() as supposed.

Comment: You are confusing "finishing" the AsyncTask with "cancelling". Are you calling the cancel() method on your AsyncTask in onPause or onStop ?

Comment: I can't cancel it from the activity, so I tried to do this: _see edit in post_
It doesn't seem to work since I don't see the 'Cancelled' message in logcat I set when it gets cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

I think.. here is the problem.

```
        Glide.with(context).
```

Cuz, here activity is destroyed and it is still using the context of destroyed activity.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is happening because your activity/context is destroyed by the time Glide is invoked. I am guessing you are on a device with aggressive GC or you have "Don't keep activities in background" enabled in the "Developer Options".

To prevent the crash, I guess it's sufficient to add a null check :

```
if(context != null && (!(Activity)context).isFinishing()) {
   updateItem()
}
```

I am not sure if Glide has weak or strong references to context. This might result in a memory leak. Ideally you should cancel the AsyncTask when destroying the activity. If you cannot take that approach, you should re-think your design.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have used this method and hope the issue has been fixed for my users. I can't seem to replicate this issue, but my beta users can.

Comment: Update: Sadly this did not fix my issue, seems a bit more complicated.

Comment: Can you confirm if you can reproduce this issue by enabling "Don't keep activities in background" in the "Developer Options" ?